# How to source a new function written in python on GDB?

Tags: python, c, function, debugging, gdb

I have written new convenience function(`greet.py`) in python in order to use it on GDB.

```
class Greet (gdb.Function):
     """Return string to greet someone.
     Takes a name as argument."""

    def __init__ (self):
         super (Greet, self).__init__ ("greet")

    def invoke (self, name):
         return "Hello, %s!" % name.string ()

Greet ()
```

Now I would like to use it on GDB as convenience function. What are the procedures I should do in order to use it while debugging a program on GDB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to write new convenience function in GDB :

1. write the function and place it under `"~/gdb/python/lib/gdb/function"`

```
import gdb 

class Salam(gdb.Function):
    """Return string to greet someone.
    Takes a name as argument."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Salam, self).__init__("salam")

    def invoke(self, name):
        return "Salam, jenap %s!" % name.string ()

Salam()
```

2. Edit "~/gdb/data-directory/Makefile.in" and under "PYTHON_FILE_LIST" add "gdb/function/salam.py"
3. ./configure
4. make
5. make install

Now, after `#gdb`
try typing : "print salam("Aman")"

In order the convenience function to work, it must have python support under GDB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered there's no built in user directory from which scripts are auto-loaded.

Usually a user would source individual scripts from their `~/.gdbinit` file, like this:

```
source /home/user/gdb/scripts/my-script.py
```

If a user really wants scripts to be auto-sourced from a directory without having to add them to their `~/.gdbinit` then this is easily done by adding the following into `~/.gdbinit`:

```
python
import os
directory = '/home/user/gdb/scripts/'
if os.path.isdir (directory):
  for filename in sorted (os.listdir(directory)):
    if filename.endswith (".py") or filename.endswith (".gdb"):
      path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
      gdb.execute ("source {}".format (path))
end
```

This will load all `*.py` and `*.gdb` scripts from `/home/user/gdb/scripts/`.